# How to pass sort by _score in springboot elastic search in @Query param

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-elasticsearch

```
@Query("{\"multi_match\": {\"query\": \"?0\", \"fields\": [\"field1\", \"field2\",\"field3\",\"field4\"], \"fuzziness\": \"AUTO\"}}")
Page<ElasticRecipe> findBySearchQueryAutoComplete(String searchTerm, Pageable pageable);
```

spring-data-elasticsearch : version 5.0.1,
springboot : 3.0.2,
java : 19

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That should be possible by adding a `Sort` parameter as 3rd one and setting it when calling the method, but it's not implemented. I just created [an issue](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-elasticsearch/issues/2449) for that and will fix this.